# Joomla 3.9.0 administrator https issue

Tags: ssl, https, joomla3.0, administrator

While editing any module i got this error 
[image].

Error
An error has occurred while fetching the JSON data: HTTP 0 status code. error

On inspect at the console below error is showing >>
[image].

**ERROR:**

The page at 'https://www.website.com/administrator/?option=com_modules&view=module&layout=edit' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.website.com/administrator/?option=com_ajax&group=system&plugin=sendStats&format=raw'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Inside the administrator area, all URLs are showing
[insecure content blocked icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh3K7.png)

**Front-end is fine.**

- I have installed SSL properly.
- I have done Force SSL -> entire site, at configuration.
- Same server, another administrator has no error.

**Please help. Couldn't find any solution.
Thank you in advance for your help.**

Comment: Did you clean the browser and Joomla Cache? If not then do once and then recheck.

Comment: @AmitRay yes, I have tried that but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

for JSON error  : This issue has been rectified. The resolution for this is to Go to Manage > Update > Find Advanced Module Manager. Alternatively go to Modules Manager and you should be download the latest version of Advanced Module Manager. JUST UPDATE THE PLUGIN and the error message will be gone. Hope this helps.

"blocked icon" are displayed for this purpose as a javascript or jquery file running that is malicious, disable the plugins that you installed on Joomla and did not exist in Joomla by default, And see if the icon disappears or not

Comment: Thank you @Arash for your answer. But I don't use Advanced Module Manager. So Advanced Module Manager is not installed. My primary concern is **Error An error has occurred while fetching the JSON data: HTTP 0 status code. error**. At inspect, as you can see, requested http url instead of https url.

Comment: You just copied it from here and pasted https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/12689